# Load data into Python from SQL server 2014

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x

I have the following code that I want to load data into Python using Jupyter Notebook:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc

conn = (
    r'DRIVER={SQL Server};'
    r'SERVER=DESKTOP-ULQTFDK\SQLSERVER2014;'
    r'DATABASE=AdventureWorks2014;'
    r'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
)
conn = pyodbc.connect(conn)
#df=pd.read_sql('select * from Person.Person',conn_str)

if conn:
    print("Yes, we are connected ")
```

When I test the connection just like above it shows that it is connected
but when I try to query the data frame like bellow

```
df=pandas.read_sql('select * from Person.Person',conn)
df.shape
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py in execute(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1403             else:
-> 1404                 cur.execute(*args)
   1405             return cur

Error: ('HY000', '[HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Connection is busy with results for another hstmt (0) (SQLExecDirectW)')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

DatabaseError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-1bc707d0534c> in <module>()
----> 1 df=pandas.read_sql('select * from Person.Person',conn
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You `imported pandas` as `pd` so use `pd`

```
df=pd.read_sql('select * from Person.Person',conn)
df.shape
```